# jquery adding content and scrolling top

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, prepend

I need to add content dynamically so once user is scrolling down it's all good,because i detect once user near bottom of the page ant than i add content so user even won't notice it , but once user is scrolling up if I add content all other page jumps dawn and user can clearly see that something is wrong.

my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height()-100) {
        $('#myparrentdiv').append(huge_content);
    }
    if($(window).scrollTop()<100) { 
        $('#myparrentdiv').prepend(huge_content); //here we get jumping content
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo prepend rather than prepent.

```
$(window).scroll(function() { if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >      
$(document).height()-100) { $('#myparrentdiv').append(huge_content); }   
if($(window).scrollTop()<100) { $('#myparrentdiv').prepend(huge_content); //here we get jumping content } });
```